# Neo4j Cypher query for all paths that contain certain nodes and relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need a cypher query that will match all paths of a certain length n that contain the specified nodes and specified edges. I developed a query, but I am getting a syntax error and I am not sure why, as I am new to cypher

```
MATCH (a, b)
WITH a, b
MATCH path = (a)-[*..n]-(b)
WHERE ALL(relName IN ['relname1', 'relname2'] 
   WHERE ANY(rel IN relationships(path) WHERE rel.display_name = relName)
AND a.name = 'node1name' and b.name = 'node2name'
RETURN path
```

The syntax error is

```
Invalid input 'a': expected "(", "ALL", "ANY" or "SHORTEST" (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7))
"MATCH (a, b)"
        ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `( )` in your first `MATCH` could be interpreted as a single node pattern. But you can declare at most a single variable in each node pattern, and so `(a, b)` raises a syntax error.

In any case, it doesn't look like you really need the first two lines. This is a valid query (if `n` is replaced with a positive integer), that binds to start nodes with name `'node1name'` and end nodes with name `'node2name'`:

```sql
MATCH path = (a)-[*..n]-(b)
WHERE all(relName IN ['relname1', 'relname2'] 
            WHERE any(rel IN relationships(path) WHERE rel.display_name = relName)) 
AND a.name = 'node1name' and b.name = 'node2name'
RETURN path
```

Comment: It would probably be more efficient if `a.name` and `b.name` were tested at beginning of `WHERE` clause.

Comment: In a query this simple, they will get rewritten to a scan / seek at the start of the plan in the same way, wherever you choose to put the predicates.

Comment: It is hard to determine whether a query is "simple". I think it is better to show general best practice, especially when writing an answer that many people may rely on for their own use cases.

Comment: Absolutely. I only added the qualifier "simple" because I didn't know off the top of my head whether there were complex queries where the plan wouldn't start with predicates on the start node(s). The placement of the start and end node predicates here doesn't violate any best practice, and I felt it would be clearer to focus on what needed fixing: removing the syntax error and the unnecessary WITH.

Comment: @FinbarGood Thank you for your answer! I now have the situation that I have a list of node names and a list of relationships and I don't know what order they are in, so I can't use the above syntax anymore, I just need all paths that contain at least those in any order, with a defined path length. I tried around a bit, but couldn't find an efficient query... Is there a way to amend this query to fulfill that requirement?

Comment: Are the first and last nodes still bound to e.g. 'node1name' and 'node2name'?